# From the Organizer, how do you reinstall your "provisioning profile" back to a "restored" iPod?

Tags: iphone, xcode, organizer

From the Organizer, how do you reinstall your "provisioning profile" back to a "restored" iPod ?
I had "restored" my iPod, but now Xcode says "No provisioned iOS device is connected" and can't build an app to the iPod.  The organizer says "This profile cannot be installed on devices" even though I just had a provisioning profile just prior to "restoring" my iPod to original settings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in Organizer, your iPod is still being used for development. Then, if that isn't the problem, make another development provisioning profile in the provisioning portal on Apple's Developer website.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the trouble of doing a new profile through Apple's Developer website.

Comment: How much trouble is it, really? I can do it in 2 minutes.